# Recreate function in redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I'm new to the Redux and I  was wondering about How to re-create this function in redux?
Problem is I don't know how to generate new button in redux,Any suggestions?

```
renderPagination = () => {
    let {pageCount} = this.props

    const paging = []

    for (let i = 1; i <= pageCount; i++) {
        paging.push(
            <button
                key={uuidv4()}
                className={'btn btn-info'}
                onClick={() => {
                    this.setState({currentPage: i})
                }}>
                {i}
            </button>
        )
    }
    return paging
}
```

Comment: this function should not be a redux store, it should be a `functional component` as it is now

Comment: So I shall move  pageCount,currentPage and itemsPerPage into this components state?

Comment: not necessarily, the component is good as it is, it expects the pageCount from the caller, and renders a list of buttons for each, you can also pass a function to the component so that the caller is responsible for the currentPage, like `<button onClick={props.onClick}>{i}<button>`

Comment: so that you dont need to move the currentPage inside this component

Comment: glad to be helpful -  and happy coding :)